# How does function `flags.DEFINE_boolean` works?

Tags: python, absl-py

I'm confused about the function `flags.DEFINE_boolean` when I'm using python's absl module. Below is my code, when I set the parameter default to `True`, I can no longer dynamically modify `is_student` to `False` via the command line.

```py
from absl import app, flags

mmap = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_boolean(
    name='is_student',
    default=True,
    help='Are you a student?',
)


def func(_):   # 'python test.py --is_student False' doesn't work
    print(mmap.is_student)  # mmap.is_student is always True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(func)
```

At the same time, I found that when setting the parameter default to `False`, as long as the `is_student` is mentioned on the command line, the `is_student` is triggered as `True`. Can I just set the default value of `flags.DEFINE_boolean` to `False`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--is_student False` doesn't mean you're setting `is_student` to `False`. The `--is_student` means you're setting `is_student` to `True`, and the `False` is interpreted as an entirely unrelated argument.

To turn off the `is_student` flag, use `--nois_student`.